# Arduino error compiling

Tags: arduino, real-time-clock

I am having a compiling error with my new code. I cannot find the anything wrong. I have searched google. Any help would be great. Please see below for the code and the error message.

Code:
http://pastebin.com/cLprnCRz

Error Message:
http://pastebin.com/azkc9QLY

Comment: hello, welcome to stack overflow, please make a simple minimal concise example of your code that contains the error, and then post it within your question. If you help us help you, we'll be happy to do so!

Comment: I am sorry but the error message is vague and I do not know where the error is coming from. I have tried multiple things but I think it has to do with the time commands, I believe that the issue is coming from the RTC.

Comment: well, cf my answer, the error is not vague at all, it's actually pretty clear ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, your error is not in your code, it's in the file you're including `sha1.h` which is implementing a virtual method from `Print.h` but with the wrong return type:

in sha1.h:

```
virtual void Sha1Class::write(uint8_t)
        ^^^^
```

in Print.h:

```
virtual size_t Print::write(uint8_t)
        ^^^^^^
```

your `sha1` library is likely to have been written for a different version of the Arduino framework.

The error is pretty clear, as it says:

```
error: conflicting return type specified for 'virtual void Sha1Class::write(uint8_t)'
error:   overriding 'virtual size_t Print::write(uint8_t)'
```

so the compiler is saying here:

> "You're defining in Print.h a method that has to be reimplemented of a given type, and when you're reimplementing it, you're giving it another type. I did my best, but really, I don't understand what you want!"

Comment: Thank you for the help I made changes to the SHA file and it works. Thank you again